# Is there a way to separate "undo close tab" from editing Undo on forms?

Tags: safari, tabs, undo-redo

If I switch tabs, I sometimes lose the "undo" action and it is replaced by "undo close tab". The reverse, where "undo close tab" can't be accessed anymore because I've typed something on a form before realizing I wanted the other tab back, is also annoying. I'm basically asking if there's a way to separate these functions - they're fundamentally two (or more, counting each page's input forms, of even each separate input box) separate "objects" that should have separate undo queues.

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but switching to a tab with no active text field gives you Undo Closed Tab back.

Comment: @Tetsujin my problem is I can't get text undo back after accidentally doing that.

Comment: Ah - can't test, on phone today.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @pela I stopped using Safari.